# Is it possible to change some form-data fields before sending the redirect response back to user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, webforms, response

I would like to redirect user's POST request with form data using 307 redirect like that

```
protected void RedirectTemporary(string url)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.StatusCode = 307;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Temporary Redirect";
    Response.RedirectLocation = ResolveClientUrl(url);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

But is it possible to change some form-data fields before sending the redirect response back to user?
`Request["someField"]` is readonly, and `Response` seems not to have any writable data collection either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself - no, its impossible, cause redirect 307 returns no form fields and simply tells browser to just repeat it's request to new location. The get out is to use `WebRequest` with new `NameValueCollection`, copied from the clients request.